# horizontal scroll bars causing bootstrap template to double in width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a horizontal scroll bar causing bootstrap template to double in width. I cannot isolate the element that is causing this to happen despite removing all elements from the template 1 by 1.

http://cruising.coresoftcloud.com/

its a mystery, would appreciate some help.

Comment: you cannot expect someone to solve your homework or freelancing problem. Show some effort and don't paste links to live sites. Create a fiddle, snippet or just paste the minimal code that you have an issue

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your main.css on line 107:

```css
.wrap-topbar {
  border-top: 4px solid #35bfb4;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /*add this*/
}
```

Comment: That's a bandaid...not a real solution

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

hi try to apply this css on line 62

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```